# admob GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar not clickable

Tags: android, click, admob

I have created an android app with GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar as lib.
My app shows the ad on the page but I am not able to click on the ads.
Can you tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is trying to shift their advertising services towards Google play services and are ending support for legacy admob sdk.

"Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play services version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then."

Source : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en_US#android

It's better to switch to google play services sdk to display ads

Comment: It showed me ads when I took the sample from developer site but when I am trying to embed that with navigation drawer , the app closes

Comment: this has frustrated the hell out of me

Comment: I'm not sure why this is causing problems in your app. i've been using google play services ads in my apps. works just fine. I cant say anything until u upload some more information about your implementation

Comment: The problem could be in the linking of your app to play services or importing the correct version file. check this page for more information:- http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html